# Creating the illusion of dynamically provisionable Web Part Zones

Tags: deployment, page-layout

I'm currently creating an application for SharePoint 2010 that leverages what I consider to be repeatable solutions I've used over and over as a consultant.

Something that I made that I liked was a metro like dashboard where people could add custom webparts (twitter, etc...) to their SharePoint landing page.

I'd like to be able to offer different grids with different layout sizes, so it feels a little like Windows 8.

The hard part is, SharePoint throws an error any time I try to dynamically add Web Part Zones.

The idea of pre-creating hidden grids that are rendered or not with JS for personalized views sounds like KLUGE waiting to happen.

Anyone have a recommendation?

Comment: Hi, did you ever come up with a suitable solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wiki page libraries (in SP 2010) seem to have the ability to change layouts on the fly.  Have you tried using them instead of a webpart page?